# Is there a way to send voice to text as a payload from Alexa to Node-Red?

Tags: automation, alexa-skills-kit, node-red

I suspect I'm just not googling the right thing but,

I'm trying to get Alexa to send variable text through to Node-Red as a payload.

the end goal will look something like this:

1. "alexa, open firefox"
2. "alexa, search for [search query]"
3. Node-red runs python with payload from Alexa

or more generically

1. "alexa, [command]"
2. "alexa, [arguments for command]"
3. Node-Red runs python with payload [arguments for command]

I can do step 1 and 3, but I'm not sure how to get Alexa to pass the raw text for interpretation by python on my PC. This is just a basic example and maybe not practical, the main point is to be able to say anything and have that [anything] arrive in python.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you can get to getting a free form speech from the user is to use '[Amazon.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#phrase-types)' intent. The main caveat of it is that it requires a carrier phrase, but it seems that this is not a problem in your case, so I recommend you give it a shot.